# using increment/decrement in bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a bash script like this;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
  "arg1x" "arg1y" "arg1z"
  "arg2x" "arg2y" "arg2z"
  "arg3x" "arg3y" "arg3z"
)

while ((i<${#arr[@]})); do
  echo "This should print arg1x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x: ${arr[i++]}"
  echo "This should print arg1y: ${arr[i++]}"
  echo "This should print arg1z: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x: ${arr[i--]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1z: ${arr[i++]}"
  echo "----------------------------------"
done
```

which should print out the list of arrays as stated in the echos (numbers are irrelevant, but the `x, y, z` parts should match with the strings in the echos). However, when I run the script, it prints out this;

```
This should print arg1x: arg1x
This should print arg1x arg1x
This should print arg1y arg1y
This should print arg1z arg1z
This should print arg1x arg1z
This should print arg1x arg1y
This should print arg1x arg1y
This should print arg1z arg1y
----------------------------------
This should print arg1x: arg1z
This should print arg1x arg1z
This should print arg1y arg2x
This should print arg1z arg2y
This should print arg1x arg2y
This should print arg1x arg2x
This should print arg1x arg2x
This should print arg1z arg2x
----------------------------------
This should print arg1x: arg2y
This should print arg1x arg2y
This should print arg1y arg2z
This should print arg1z arg3x
This should print arg1x arg3x
This should print arg1x arg2z
This should print arg1x arg2z
This should print arg1z arg2z
----------------------------------
This should print arg1x: arg3x
This should print arg1x arg3x
This should print arg1y arg3y
This should print arg1z arg3z
This should print arg1x arg3z
This should print arg1x arg3y
This should print arg1x arg3y
This should print arg1z arg3y
----------------------------------
This should print arg1x: arg3z
This should print arg1x arg3z
This should print arg1y 
This should print arg1z 
This should print arg1x 
This should print arg1x 
This should print arg1x 
This should print arg1z 
----------------------------------
```

It prints it out 5 times while it should be 3 since there are only 3 args in the array (for this example), plus, the args doesn't match with their corresponding.

I've tried playing around with the `i` stuff but couldn't figure it out.

How can I do this?

UPDATE:

I've edited the script like this, which seems to be printing out correct values now;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr=(
  "arg1x" "arg1y" "arg1z"
  "arg2x" "arg2y" "arg2z"
  "arg3x" "arg3y" "arg3z"
)

while ((i<${#arr[@]})); do
  echo "This should print arg1x: ${arr[i+0]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x ${arr[i+0]}"
  echo "This should print arg1y ${arr[i+1]}"
  echo "This should print arg1z ${arr[i+2]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1x ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg1z ${arr[i+2]}"
  echo "----------------------------------"
done
```

But now it loops through arg1 only (not arg2 and 3) and it never stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `++` and `--` is going to be really confusing when things get this complicated. For one thing, you have to make sure you increment 3 times more than you decrement; you have 3 increments and 1 decrement, so the net is only 2 increments, so you're off by one each iteration (that's why it's getting off after the first iteration). Second, you have to carefully keep track of where it is at each point to figure out if you're going to get x, y, or z. It's going to be much easier to just increment +3 in the loop itself, and then use `[i]` for x, `[i+1]` for y, and `[i+2]` for z. Since those don't change `i`, they just *work* no matter how many times and what order you use them in. Something like this:

```
declare -a arr=(
  "arg1x" "arg1y" "arg1z"
  "arg2x" "arg2y" "arg2z"
  "arg3x" "arg3y" "arg3z"
)

for ((i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i+=3)); do    # Iterate the array, 3 at a time
  echo "This should print arg(something)x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)y: ${arr[i+1]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)z: ${arr[i+2]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)x: ${arr[i]}"
  echo "This should print arg(something)z: ${arr[i+2]}"
  echo "----------------------------------"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're trying to iterate through the array, perhaps you would like to modify your code into something like this.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo $i
done
```

*edit
Maybe this one?

```
for i in 0 1 2; do
    echo ${arr[$((i * 3 + 0))]}
    echo ${arr[$((i * 3 + 1))]}
    echo ${arr[$((i * 3 + 2))]}
done
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I separate arrays with this? like, if I want to print `arg2z`, how can I do this?

Comment: or like if I want to print them like this; `echo "${arr[i++]} ${arr[i++]} ${arr[i++]}";` so it prints `arg1x arg1y arg1z` side by side and goes to the next line with arg2 and so on.